# How to log into container in Azure?

Tags: azure, containers

I deploy a docker image inside Azure Container Instance. The application itself will write some log into the file. Is there some way I can log into the container to view these logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
az container exec --resource-group <group-name> --name <container-group-name> --exec-command "<command>"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-exec

You could also create a context with docker and then use docker commands.

```sh
docker context create aci myacicontext
docker context use myacicontext
docker logs <CONTAINER_ID>
docker exec -t <CONTAINER_ID> COMMAND
```

https://docs.docker.com/cloud/aci-integration/#create-an-aci-context

Answer (score 0):

Have found the answer.

```sh
az container logs  --name your-container-name --resource-group your-resource-group-name
```

or

```sh
az container exec --name your-container-name --resource-group your-resource-group-name --exec-command "cat /home/yourname/xxx.log"
```